# Http failure for getting base64 string

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

This is my code:

```
getPhoto(employeeId: string): Observable<any[]> {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'responseType': 'json'
    })

    const url = `/Emps/GetPhoto`;
    const params = new HttpParams({
      fromObject: { employeeId },
    });
    return this.http.get<any[]>(url, { params, headers });
  }
```

And this is what is returned from that method:

> data:image/svg;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHhtbG5zOnhsaW5rPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8xOTk5L3hsaW5rIiB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgNDY4IDI4MCIgd
> ...

The method returns Success 200, however in console I get SyntaxError: Unexpected token d in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse () at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad, and the getPhoto subscribe debugger is never hit. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You get that error because response is not a valid json object

Answer (score 3):

The [default response type](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/11.2.12/packages/common/http/src/client.ts#L492) for Angular `HttpClient`'s GET method is `json`. Try to set the response type explicitly

```js
return this.http.get<any[]>(url, { params, headers }, responseType: 'text' });
```

You could also use `blob` or `arraybuffer` if it's more appropriate to your requirement. It's type definition is as follows

```js
responseType?: 'arraybuffer'|'blob'|'json'|'text'
```

**Update 1**: pushed `responseType` outside the `options` object

Comment: return this.http.get<any[]>(url, { params, responseType: 'text' });
If I do this, I get syntax error Type 'Observable<ArrayBuffer>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<any[]>'.

Comment: @petko_stankoski: You're expecting an array of `any` while the response isn't. Try changing the return type to `getPhoto(employeeId: string): Observable<any>`.

Comment: Still I get error: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 15, '(url: string, options: { headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe: "events"; params?: HttpParams | { [param: string]: string | string[]; }; reportProgress?: boolean; responseType?: "json"; withCredentials?: boolean; }): Observable<...>', gave the following error.
    Type '"text"' is not assignable to type '"json"'.

Comment: @petko_stankoski: That would by my mistake. The `responseType` as shown in the overload definition, is supposed to be outside the `options` object. I've updated the answer. Please see if it works now.

Comment: Another error: Cannot find name 'responseType'.ts